# What is the current format for the border attribute?

Tags: html, css

I am using inline attributes to style email signatures. I have always used border="0". Has this now been changed to border=0? If yes, can the same be said for width=, height=, rowspan=, colspan=, etc.?

Both seem to work but would rather remove the quotation marks if they are not needed.